# Organize / Sort data of the array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell

I have an array which holds the logon info of the users as objects. Here are the printings of that array:

```
PS> $Write-Out $data1
System.Object System.Object System.Object System.Object System.Object System.Object System.Object

PS> $data1 
ComputerName       User               Time                      Action                            
------------       ----               -------------------       ------
DC1                usr1               05/06/2013 11:51:35       logoff                         
DC1                usr1               05/06/2013 11:46:24       logon                         
DC1                usr1               05/06/2013 11:42:05       logoff
DC2                usr2               05/06/2013 11:44:08       logon
DC2                Administrator      05/06/2013 11:43:50       logoff
DC2                Administrator      05/06/2013 11:42:53       logon
DC2                Administrator      05/06/2013 11:40:27       logoff
```

I want to convert this array so that I can see logon and logoff times on the same line like this:

```
PS> $data2
ComputerName      User               Time LOGON           Time LOGOFF      
------------      ----               -------------------  -------------------                  
DC1               usr1               05/06/2013 11:46:24  05/06/2013 11:51:35                         
DC1               usr1                                    05/06/2013 11:42:05       
DC2               usr2               05/06/2013 11:44:08                        
DC2               Administrator      05/06/2013 11:42:53  05/06/2013 11:43:50
DC2               Administrator                           05/06/2013 11:40:27
```

Can you help me with converting the $data1 array to $data2 array?

Comment: Can you give the Command line that generate $data1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will give you the same `$data2`, based on your `$data1`, but might contain bugs.

```
$data2 = $data1 | Group-Object -Property ComputerName, User | foreach { # group
    foreach ($r in $_.Group) { # record
        if ($r.Action -eq "logon") {
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Time LOGOFF"=$off; "Time LOGON"=$r.Time; User=$r.User; ComputerName=$r.ComputerName};
            $off = $null;
            continue;
        } else {$off = $r.Time;}
    }
    if ($off) {New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Time LOGOFF"=$off; "Time LOGON"=""; User=$r.User; ComputerName=$r.ComputerName}; $off=$null;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your own object and assign the values from your $data1.
You could do something like :

```
    $readableData1| Select ComputerName,User #Just an example to create a simple object
    $data1|%{ #Foreach line in $data1

    $readabledata.ComputerName = $_.ComputerName.ToString()
    $readabledata.User= $_.User.ToString()

    $array+= $readableData1
    }

echo $array
```

Comment: Custom objects from $data1 would be a way;) The code doesn't work but I got the idea. Thanks!